# DynamoDB update error Invalid UpdateExpression: An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to perform an update on DynamoDB table.

The code is (Node.js):

```
    let params = {
        TableName: Organizations.Table,
        Key: {
            'ID': event.ID
        },
        UpdateExpression: 'SET #OrgName = :org, #Description = :desc',
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#OrgName': 'OrgName',
            '#Description': 'Description'
        },
        ExpressionAtributeValues: {
            ':org': event.OrgName,
            ':desc': event.Description
        },
        ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
    };
    this.docClient.update(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        return cb(null, data);
    });
```

The event object has all the properties needed.

After executing I get an error:

> Invalid UpdateExpression: An expression attribute value used in
>   expression is not defined; attribute value: :desc

I just followed the examples from DynamoDB docs.
When I change the order of set values, e.g. to `SET #Description = :desc, #OrgName = :org` the error I get will be about attribute value `:org`. I also tried to specify expression attribute values explicitly, didn't help.

I can't get what is wrong.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure that event is defined? Add a console.log(JSON.stringify(params)) just before you call docClient.update(..)

Comment: I think notionquest's answer below solves the issue.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake in `ExpressionAtributeValues` (i.e. 't' missing) which is causing the problem.

Please try the below. It should work.

```
UpdateExpression : "SET #OrgName = :org, #Description = :desc",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#OrgName' : 'OrgName',
        '#Description' : 'Description'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {':org' : 'new org value', 
        ':desc' : 'new desc value'          
    },
    ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
```