# AWS SDK Java DynamoDB - Query with Expression Attribute Name - An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Similar to: [I cannot query my dynamodb table from aws lambda due to wrong filterexpression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63557453/i-cannot-query-my-dynamodb-table-from-aws-lambda-due-to-wrong-filterexpression) and [DynamoDB update error Invalid UpdateExpression: An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833163/dynamodb-update-error-invalid-updateexpression-an-expression-attribute-value-us)

I am trying to code a way to query DynamoDB tables using partial matches on Partition Key / Sort Key in Java.

The DynamoDB table I am trying to access has a Partition key of "Type" (A restricted key word in DynamoDB, I know, but not my choice) and a Sort key of "Id". I know the "Type" but not the full Id, so I have researched the Query method using AWS SDK 2.x source code and have implemented as shown below:

```
DynamoDBClient dynamoDbClient = DynamoDbClient.builder()
  .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
  .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCredentials))
  .build();

String idKey = "wholeIdKey";
String idValue = "partialIdValue";
String typeValue = "typeValue";

Map<String, String> expressionNames = new HashMap<>();
expressionNames.put("#t", "Type");

QueryRequest request = QueryRequest.builder()
  .tableName(tableName)
  .keyConditionExpression("begins_with ( " + idKey + ", :" + idValue + " )
     AND #t = :" + typeValue)
  .expressionAttributeNames(expressionNames)
  .build();

QueryResponse response = dynamoDbClient.query(request);
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException: 
Invalid KeyConditionExpression: An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined; attribute value: :typeValue
```

It's as if it's not recognizing the fact that I have told the code use the Expression Attribute Names feature to replace the "#t" with "Type" (Which is a reserved keyword in DynamoDB)

Can anyone help?

**EDIT: References for code:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/javav2-dynamodb-src-main-java-com-example-dynamodb-Query.java.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html

https://www.javadoc.io/static/software.amazon.awssdk/dynamodb/2.7.14/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/model/QueryRequest.html#expressionAttributeNames--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Fixed Code for whoever wants it in the future*** (Thanks to [@aherve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103340/aherve) and [@MattTimmermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5483526/matt-timmermans))

```
DynamoDBClient dynamoDbClient = DynamoDbClient.builder()
  .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
  .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCredentials))
  .build();

String idKey = "wholeIdKey";
String idValue = "partialIdValue";
String typeValue = "typeValue";
String typeKey = "typeKey";

Map<String, String> expressionNames = new HashMap<>();
expressionNames.put("#t", "Type");
expressionNames.put("#i", "Id");

Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionValues = new HashMap<>();
expressionValues.put(":typeName", AttributeValue.builder().s(typeValue).build());
expressionValues.put(":idName", AttributeValue.builder().s(idValue).build());

QueryRequest request = QueryRequest.builder()
  .tableName(tableName)
  .keyConditionExpression("#t = :typeName AND begins_with ( #i, :idName )")
  .expressionAttributeNames(expressionNames)
  .expressionAttributeValues(expressionValues)
  .build();

response = dynamoDbClient.query(request);
```

Answer (score 2):

The name is fine, but you're prefixing both values with ':'.  That causes a lookup in `ExpressionAttributeValues`, which you did not provide.

Never try to write dynamic values directly into the query string.

Comment: Okay, so should I remove the colon if I'm trying to write direct values instead of Expression Attribute Values?

Comment: Amazon doesn't document any way to write the values  directly in the expression.

Comment: Ahh okay. thanks. I provided ExpressionAttributeValues and it's working. Ta.

Answer (score 1):

Your expressionAttributeName looks fine, but you forgot to provide a value for  `:typeValue` so dynamoDB cannot know what to look for.

In addition to what you did, you need to add an `expressionAttributeValue` where you can provide proper values. [See documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeValues.html)